# replace last seven characters of string

Tags: php

I have a string and I want to replace the last 7 charators of the string with "#". For example I have "MerryChristmasu87yujh7" I want to replace "87yujh7" with seven "#######". So, the final string will be "MerryChristmasu#######".

I have tried the follow code but it returns "MerryChristmasu#######1". It does not convert all seven ending characters.

```
$string = "MerryChristmasu87yujh7";
$match = substr($string, -7, -1);
$result = str_replace($match, "#######", $string);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be...

```
$match = substr($string, -7);
```

... without the final -1. But in fact, it's far better done with...

```
$result = substr($string, 0, -7) . str_repeat('#', 7);
```

... or, more generic:

```
$coverWith = function($string, $char, $number) {
  return substr($string, 0, -$number) . str_repeat($char, $number);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$cuttedString = substr("your string", -7);
```

this should do the job.