# PHP: Asterisk only last 4 digits of number

Tags: php, html, password-hash

Hi i want to change the last 4 digits of number with asterisk
For example: 123456789101

I want it to become 12345678**** in database (PHPMyAdmin)

This is my code

```
 if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        
    $voter = $_POST['voters_id']; (**I want the voters_id to be asterisk only last 4 digits**)
    }
        
    
 $sql = "INSERT INTO voters (voters_id, password) VALUES ('$voter', '$password')";
            
    if($conn->query($sql)){
                
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
                
    echo 'alert("Voters sucessfully insert")';
                
    echo '</script>';
                
    echo ("<script>location.href='index.php'</script>");
        
    }
        
    
            
    else{
               
     $_SESSION['error'] = $conn->error;
            
    }
        
    }
```

Is there any idea on how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hashing means something specific in programming, but you example appears to be just replacing the four digits with asterisks. Are you redacting/anonymizing? You don’t normally concatenate a hashed string with something else

Comment: ahh yes asterisk that's the keyword i want Thank You Chris!
@ChrisHaas

Comment: Please update your question then, because I think you just want to replace the last four characters of a string with asterisks

Comment: Alright noted Chris! @ChrisHaas

Comment: So if you are going to replace last 4 characters in a string with asterisks to store in a database , how are you going to get the the original values back?

Comment: @AkmalKhairi I updated my post, should work for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace last seven characters of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977920/replace-last-seven-characters-of-string)

Answer (score 1):

Edited it to match what you want; here ya go:

```
    $id = "0123456789";

    $eid = function() use ($id){
        $half1 = substr($id, 0, strlen($id) -  4);
        return $half1."****";
    };
```

Input:

```
0123456789
```

Output

```
012345****
```

Live Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ad1e3e028e696b1e8befe5e9a971ba468ba4d9e

I just don't understand how you're going to get the original numbers back from the asterisks but to each is their own lol.

Comment: It works but you're correct I can't receive the original numbers back. Maybe I need to find other way to store the asterisk and receive the original numbers back. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php echo substr($phone, 0, -4) . "****" ; ?>
```

credits to https://beta.openai.com/playground

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32966511)